# Exporting data from a table in SQL Server using ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, xml, sql-server-2008

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2008. I need to create a XML file which looks like:

```
 <cat>
   <name> "Categories"</name>
   <link> "link"</link>
 </cat>
```

The `Categories` and `link` values should be added from the database.

I have tried everything but I cannot get it to work. DO I have to create a XML file in ASP to do this?

These values are in the same table but there are other columns in the table as well.

My code looks something like this:

```
        SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
        //sqlcmd.CommandText = "Select * from Categories";
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da = new       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Categories", "Data Source=something;Initial Catalog=My Database;Integrated Security=True");
        da.Fill(ds);

      int rows;
      rows = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

      int i;

      for (i = 0; i <= rows - 1; i++)
      {
          string Categories = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString();
          string address = "https://www.something.com/";
          string link = address + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString();
      }

      ds.WriteXml(@"c:\output.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

Can someone please give me a detailed solution to this problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
sqlcmd.CommandText = "Select * from Categories";
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da = new       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Categories", "Data Source=something;Initial Catalog=My Database;Integrated Security=True");
da.Fill(ds);

      int rows;
      rows = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

      int i;
xmlwr.WriteStartElement("Cat");
      for (i = 0; i <= rows - 1; i++)
      {
xmlwr.WriteStartElement("name");
xmlwr.xmlwr.WriteString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString());
xmlwr.WriteEndElement;

xmlwr.WriteStartElement("link");
xmlwr.xmlwr.WriteString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString());
xmlwr.WriteEndElement;

      }
xmlwr.WriteEndElement;
      ds.WriteXml(@"c:\output.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

Comment: Thank you. But It displays an error at "xmlwr". Do I need to define something??

Comment: and what if I need something like
<name = "some name" date = "today's date" time = "current time">
to be displayed at the top of the XML document??

Comment: Yes you have to define xmlwr. And if you need like what you mentioned in comment,then use WriteAttributeString

Comment: Don't you think that da = fill(ds) will fill the table with all the columns from the database before I add my selected values to it??

Comment: Yes this will ass all the columns from Categories table.If you want specific columns then use "select col1,col2 from categories"

Comment: i can do that but but i need to append some text in the "link" column before saving it to XML file. How can this be done.
I also think that using "fill" will automatically write the values to the database. I have been looking at this for a whole day now. Glad if you could help

Comment: What I can suggest here is,you append waht all column you need in the select query as one column. For ex: Select col1 as name,col2+col3+col4 as link from categories